# My Instant Messaging Project Won't Work Like in the Xcode Tutorial

Tags: ios, xcode

So I was just trying to create a simple instant messaging application on my Xcode 5.0.2. I downloaded the free beta SDK from c2call.com and I followed exactly what their video instructed. However once I tried to build, atleast a dozen issues popped up.

Heres the link to the tutorial:
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qyp_BFORvIk

One of the comments said that one possible reason might be because I need to set my Xcode 5 to default in build settings, but I'm not sure how. Does anyone know what I should do?

Comment: You'll have to elaborate on what kind of errors you get..

Comment: Edit your questions to include the dozen issues that pop up. Else, we will never know how to help you.